# Strange � character in the file I have opened

Tags: python, xml, encoding, character-encoding

I have opened a .dat file in Python but it seems to be corrupted with � after each < character.
My opening code is:

```
    DataFileIn = open(datFileName, "r") 
    DataList = DataFileIn.readline() 
    DataList.decode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')    
    logging.info( DataList )
    DataFileIn.close()
```

My output is

```
INFO:......<�?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><�ETSParameterType><�BlobParameter><�CommissioningMode>0<�/CommissioningMode><�NightMode>0<�/NightMode><�SceneObjects>1<�/SceneObjects><�EffectObjects>0<�/EffectObjects> ...
```

When I open the file in Notepad++ it says UCS-2 Little Endian when I would expect it to say UTF-8. Please help.

Comment: It is the [U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](https://codepoints.net/U+FFFD); often used when decoding of a character failed. It is in the original file, because you used `errors='strict'`.

Comment: Note that you **discard** the result of `DataList.decode()`! Decoding doesn't alter a string object in-place. What happens when you do `DataList = DataList.decode('utf-8')` instead?

Comment: Also, can you give us the output of `logging.info(repr(DataList))`, **but not decoded**? That'll give us the original raw data.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `open(datFileName, "rb")` if you are going to decode the content? Imo `open(datFileName, "r")` is already decoded, so it doesn't make sense to decode it again?

Comment: DataList = DataList.decode('UTF-8')     makes no difference.

Comment: open(datFileName, "rb")     makes no difference.

Comment: logging.info(repr(DataList)), but not decoded? gives me the following               '<\x00?\x00x\x00m\x00l\x00 \x00v\x00e\x00r\x00s\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00=\x00"\x001\x00.\x000\x00"\x00 \x00e\x00n\x00c\x00o\x00d\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00=\x00"\x00U\x00T\x00F\x00-\x008\x00"\x00?\x00>\x00<\x00E\x00T\x00S\x00P  ...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the information.

Comment: And yes, you have UTF-16 data, not UTF-8. Notepad++ was correct (UCS-2 is very closely related to UTF-16, the difference being mostly in how surrogates are treated).

Answer (score 1):

You have UTF-16 data, in little-endian ordering, not UTF-8. The file was saved using the wrong encoding, or alternatively, the `encoding` information in the XML declaration is wrong.

Decode this as UTF-16 with the `utf-16-le` codec:

```
DataList = DataList.decode(encoding='utf-16-le')
```

You need to use the `utf-16-le` codec rather than plain `utf-16` because the [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is missing.